# Limit access to socket end point

Tags: box2d, html-canvas, websocket

I'm developing a multiplayer canvas game based on socket.io and box2d physics engine. Is there a way to limit connections to my socket endpoint and only allow connections from a specific domain?

```
window.socket = io.connect('http://mysite:8080');
```

I don't want people to be able to use my end point which is currently possible. They could just use the above code and then "manipulate" the clients logic based on the `emits` from the servers response.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you're asking. You need to limit the use of a particular socket? Or you want to prevent connections to your server apart from your client application?

Comment: Yes the idea is to prevent connections to my endpoint (server), apart from the client application in my domain ...

Comment: Impossible. Host can be spoofed.

Comment: @Paraknight If thats impossible how does Agario deal with this then?

Comment: Maybe you could try to solve it some other way: some kind of authentication maybe?

Comment: Agario probably doesn't do what you think it's doing. Try making whatever request you think is protected while spoofing the origin header.

Comment: Also generally with online multiplayer games, the server is authoritative and assumes the client is a cheater. The server should know what is "correct" and prevent or kick clients that don't match up. IIRC agar.io had a pretty big bot problem - that's your proof. That's where bot detection and IP bans come in play.

Comment: How matter how clever you build your system, a player (and/or hacker) can always manipulate everything about your game client, don't waste much time with clever solutions making the client unable to cheat, make the server (which is much harder for hackers to manipulate) invincible to client cheating and intentional spam. Make it authoritative like @Paraknight suggested, study up on game networking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of a research regarding Socket.io I realised you can control the origin that is connecting to your game (The Client) using the origin option,
you can read about it over here - [Socket.IO server API](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#).

if I understood you correctly you wish to control the connections and you want to accept connections only from a specific uri (correct me if i'm wrong please), now if you dig into Socket.IO code you will find the following

```
 var origin = request.headers.origin || request.headers.referer
  , origins = this.get('origins');

...

var parts = url.parse(origin);
parts.port = parts.port || 80;
var ok =
  ~origins.indexOf(parts.hostname + ':' + parts.port) ||
  ~origins.indexOf(parts.hostname + ':*') ||
  ~origins.indexOf('*:' + parts.port);
```

which is checking your server.js file and looking for the following line

```
io.set('origins', 'www.mydomain.com:3000');
```

this is where you want to define the allowed domains.

Comment: Except that the origin header can very easily be spoofed by a client, so you would definitely need some kind of authentication on top of that.

Comment: theres always the option of using Tokens to make things harder for cheaters from cheating, but theres always going to be some sort of a hack to bypass any system.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the box you're connecting to, couldn't you add a firewall policy to only allow a specific domain? If you don't have access to the box directly, perhaps whatever hosting service you're using allows some form of firewall control for access to your endpoint? As far as I know, that's the only way to truly prevent connections.

There are other solutions you could probably draw up with a little creativity. Authentication and disconnection of users who the server discovers are cheating is one potential way of approaching this. Usually with games involving a server, you want to make sure the server controls the actual game logic so that there's no way a hacked client can cheat.

Answer (score 1):

The server receives the `connect` event when the client connects to the socket.io server.

At this point, you can implement a simple verification to make sure that the person connected is supposed to be using your application.

To do so, the next event the client **must** send is a `sign in` event with some credentials (a token, for example). You can then validate the token, and only if the user has been validated should the other `socket.on` events be allowed to properly run.

If the user doesn't verify himself, you will immediately disconnect the socket. (If you want to get fancy, grab the IP address and blacklist the user.)

I'm not sure why the restriction has to necessarily be tied to the domain--can't that be faked? If you're really focused on security, make the client provide data that only your server can possibly provide. Then validate this data and you will know that the client is legit.